# Querying all posts from friends with the post creator's user data in Gremlin

Tags: mongodb, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am trying to implement a social media functionality in an app where

- a **User:me** has **User:friends**
- each **User** has **Posts**
- each **Post** can have **Comments**

currently I can fetch all posts the user's friends using

`g.V().has("name", "test1").both("is_friend").both("posted_by").values("post_body").toList()`

which returns

```
{
  "status_code": 200,
  "data": "['test3 post', 'test4 post', 'test5 post']",
  "time": 0.22941160202026367
}
```

but what I need is to query the posts with its author's data something like

```
{
  posts: {
    post_body: "test3 post",
    author: {
      name: "test3"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I do this in gremlin?

Also is this the best way of using graphdbs?

I also thought about using neptune to handle the relationships part of the function, and having mongodb contain all the data that needs to be displayed.

e.g
Fetching all **post id's** from friends. Then querying the **post data** in mongodb.

Is this a better use for graphdbs?

Comment: Have you looked at the `project` step? You could use it to generate a map of all the results you need. As to storing the posts outside the graph I think that is a good thing to consider. If the posts are likely to be lengthy, one implementation is to view the graph as an index of all the activity and include references to the actual posts instead of the post text. I have seen people do it both ways.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence will check `project` step. I have actually tried implementing it only using mongodb alone. The queries were very complex and I'm afraid it won't scale very well when there will be plenty of users. Now I'm checking out graphdbs and I have realized graphdbs are really great when querying the *edges* but not so well with the inside nodes. That's why I'm considering using a hybrid of both. My next concern would be the cost. Because it would mean we will have to use aws neptune and aws documentdb.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence also we will have a real-time chat functionally too. And I'm afraid *graphdbs* are not suitable for that kind of use case.

Comment: I have seen people build chat applications backed by a GraphDB but of course all use cases are different and have different requirements.

Comment: I added an example of using nested `project` steps as an answer. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that builds a structure like the one you describe using nested `project` steps. As I don't have your data I used the air-route data set but hopefully this shows the pattern I had in mind for your query.

```
g.V('3').
  project('airport','route-data').
    by('code').
    by(project('in-count','out-count').
         by(__.in().count()).
         by(out().count()))
```

When run in the console you get this output.

```
gremlin> g.V('3').
......1>   project('airport','route-data').
......2>     by('code').
......3>     by(project('in-count','out-count').
......4>          by(__.in().count()).
......5>          by(out().count()))   
==>[airport:AUS,route-data:[in-count:82,out-count:80]]
```